# Typed property Spatie\Feed\FeedItem::$author must not be accessed before initialization

Tags: php, laravel, rss

I am using laravel spatie/laravel-feed for generate feed for my blog site

here is the method for get all item

```
    public static function getFeedItems()
{
   return Post::all();
}
```

Here is the method for generate data

```
    public function toFeedItem(): FeedItem
{
    return FeedItem::create([
        'id' => $this->id,
        'title' => $this->title,
        'summary' => $this->meta_description,
        'updated' => $this->updated_at,
        'link' => url('/', $this->slug),
        'authorName' => $this->title,
    ]);
}
```

I have added this in my web.php

```
Route::feeds();
```

i have added the link in my view like this

```
 @include('feed::links')
```

when i am visiting this link then it's showing this error

Comment: Where are you setting the `author` property on your `FeedItem`?

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/spatie/laravel-feed here have like this

```
 return FeedItem::create([
        'id' => $this->id,
        'title' => $this->title,
        'summary' => $this->summary,
        'updated' => $this->updated_at,
        'link' => $this->link,
        'authorName' => $this->authorName,
    ]);
```

In array we can't use like this

```
authorName' => $this->authorName,
```

soltuion to use

'author' => $this->authorName,